# Looping through select tags and creating an array or string

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop through select tags with the following output:

"1 dropdown1, 1 dropdown2, 2 dropdown3, 2 dropdown4, 3 dropdown5, 3 dropdown5...... "

string or array.

This is what I have so far but I'm stuck

```
var selects = document.getElementById("getAllRecordsDiv").getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var l = 0; l < selects.length; l++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var options = i + " " + selects[l].options[selects[l].selectedIndex].text;
    }            
}

    <div id="getAllRecordsDiv" style="border: 2px solid gray; padding: 5px; display: none">        
       <select name="" id="dd1" style="" onchange="">
          <option value="0">one</option>
          <option value="0">two</option>            
       </select>
       <select name="" id="dd2" style="" onchange="">
          <option value="0">three</option>
          <option value="0">four</option>
       </select>
       <select name="" id="dd3" style="" onchange="">
          <option value="0">five</option>
          <option value="0">six</option>            
       </select>
       <select name="" id="dd5" style="" onchange="">
         <option value="0">seven</option>
         <option value="0">eight</option>           
       </select>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your final explanation I understand what you needed. Here goes:

```
var selects = document.getElementById("getAllRecordsDiv").getElementsByTagName("select");
var mainCount = countTo2 = 1;
var strOptions = '';
for (var l = 0; l < selects.length; l++) {
    var options = selects[l].getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
         var option = mainCount + " " +  options[i].text + ", ";                    
         strOptions += option;
         countTo2++;
         if (countTo2 > 2) {
            countTo2 = 1;
            mainCount++;
         }
    }            
}

alert(strOptions);
```

The final (I believe) example is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/53j3cgo2/6/

Here is a more "advanced" example for you to study a bit:

```
function nodeListToArray(nodeList) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);
}

var selects = nodeListToArray(document.getElementById("getAllRecordsDiv").getElementsByTagName("select"));
var cnt = 1;
var options = '';
selects.forEach(function(select) {
    nodeListToArray(select.getElementsByTagName("option"))
        .forEach(function(option) {
            options += ((cnt+(cnt % 2))/2)  + " " +  option.text + ", ";                    
            cnt++;
        });
});

alert(options);
```

It's here:

https://jsfiddle.net/53j3cgo2/10/

There could be much better ways to do this. I invite you study more about JS objects, AMD and IIFEs ok ? :)

Comment: Thanks Nelson for your help. I edited my question and included the select tags I am working with. This what I get now.."0 one1 one0 three1 three0 five1 five0 seven1 seven" but I want it like this ""0 one, 0 three,1 five,1 seven".

Comment: just add  `+ ", "` to the end of the line that starts with `var option`.  Edited the question to include your request. I also changed the example in jsfiddle.

Comment: if the error is the order just invert the for order. Like this: `for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {    for (var l = 0; l < selects.length; l++) {`

Comment: So close..I'm getting this.".0 one, 1 one, 0 three, 1 three, 0 five, 1 five, 0 seven, 1 seven," But would like this "0 one, 0 three, 1 five, 1 seven," I could use jquery as well. Thanks.

Comment: As I said above... invert the for lines.

Comment: Getting this now..0 one, 0 three, 0 five, 0 seven, 1 one, 1 three, 1 five, 1 seven,

Comment: Then I'm not understanding the logic of the loop you want. You want to divide options by 2 options each ?

Comment: I want to add the same number to every two drop downs.. 0 dropdown1, 0 dropdown2, 1 dropdown3, 1 dropdown4, 2 dropdown5, 2 dropdown6 and so on.

Comment: Oh... now I understood. Edited the answer. I belive now it's ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nelson.